# Returning incorrect parameter on Connection String verification

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, desktop-application

I would like to know if there is any easy way to test if a connectionString is valid and if not, which parameter of it is incorrect (connect timeout, TrustServerCertificate, etc...)

Comment: Please post the code if any that you have written to try to accomplish this. We can then provide help on simplifying or correcting it.

Comment: No, there is none

Comment: Right now im only testing if the connection is possible, i haven't found a way to return which parameter is incorrect, i dont know if i was clear but my connection string is correct, just wanted to make a function that in case i wanted to alter it and beeing unable to connect would return whats the problem @ShriramRamesh

Comment: Alright thanks anyway @Rahul

Comment: The best way is to _actually try to connect_.

Comment: Maybe the [SqlConnectionStringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder) documentation holds some secrets.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Yeah, thats what i currently have

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I've looked into it, but looks like it would have to be from scratch, from what i can see